# Geth: process receipts (clique)

Tags: go-ethereum, clique

we set up our own ethereum instance using geth and the "clique" consensus mechanism. We have now 20 nodes and only 1 of them is a miner.
My problem is: It seems like, that only the miner node is able to process transaction receipts (read event logs and so on) and all the other nodes fail. Why is that? Could it be because we used "fast" as syncmode?

Edit: ok, it seems like we are able to process receipts from other nodes. But: Transactions coming from other nodes, but the miner node, are pending for a very long time. Even though the gas limit is set to 20.000.000 and a transaction on averages uses only 300.000. It seems like we never get more than 1 or 2 transactions in one block

Edit: We were able to solve the problem. Our genesis file contained the parameter "MinGasLimit". Not sure why, but we removed this parameter and everything works fine now.